Finding a solution to a differential equation that satisfies an initial condition

Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}L}{\mathrm{d}t} = k L^2 \ln t, 
\qquad 
L(1) = -9
$$

In my class today, we ended on this problem that I didn't get to finish but would like to for my notes. Could I have help finishing?
So far, I have done the following:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}L}{\mathrm{L^2}}  =k \ln t \, dt
$$
$$
\int \frac{\mathrm{d}L}{\mathrm{L^2}} =k \int \ln t \, dt
$$
$$
-\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{L}} = k(t \,\ln t-t)+C
$$
$$
L(1)=-9 \rightarrow t=1, L=-9
$$
$$
-\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{-9}}=k(1 \, \ln (1) - 1) +C
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{9}}=-k + C \rightarrow C=1+k
$$
$$
-\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{L}}=k(t \, \ln t-t) +1+k
$$
Could you help me finish the final answer? I believe it should be in the form of L =, but I could be wrong. Thanks
Edit, the solution was:
$$
L= \frac{\mathrm{-1}}{\mathrm{k(t \ln (t)-t)+\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{9}}+k}}
$$

Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Are you taking a course in differential equations? If so, what tools have you developed? What have you tried in this case? Where did you get stuck? You have to show a lot more effort if you expect anybody to put in effort to write out an answer to help you. Please edit your post to include more work on the problem. Also, read this.

@Moo It's supposed to be in the form of L = , not L(t) =,  this is why I got lost. I know I am close, but I cannot seem to get it since I got stressed. Here is a video that shows a similar question that results in L=
link

@Moo, please look at the YouTube video I linked showing this. I don't know how else to explain.

@Moo, I will provide a screenshot of the problem. My Professor has us enter our answers as we complete them in class to make sure we pay attention and grades on participation, but I had to leave early, so I missed the last part of this problem. Apologies for my confusion.   link

When is doubt, AI it out. I had AI convert it so the same format as it was asking and it was
$$
L= \frac{\mathrm{-1}}{\mathrm{k(tln(t)-t)+\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{9}}+k}}
$$

To correctly apply initial conditions, try doing definite integration when separating variables.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{L^2}\frac{dL}{dt} &= k\ln t \\
\int_0^t \frac{1}{L^2}\frac{dL}{d\tau} ~d \tau &= \int_1^t k \ln \tau~d\tau \\
\int_{L(1)}^{L(t)}\frac{1}{L^2}~dL &= \int_1^t k \ln \tau~d\tau \\
\frac{1}{L(1)} - \frac{1}{L(t)} &= k(t \ln t - t + 1) \\
L(t) &= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{L(1)} - k(t \ln t - t + 1)}  \\
&= \frac{-1}{\frac{1}{9}+ k(t \ln t - t + 1)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
